# how to have scrollbars on an inner div, not on the dialog

Tags: html

In the context of SharePoint, I call a dialog. SharePoint basically created a lightbox div and puts my html inside. I have no control over where it decides to display the dialog, nor of its dimensions, and not even of the CSS used for the containing page. In other words, whatever I can do must be included inside my own html/javascript/CSS.

The problem arrives because my html contains this one div that is sometimes
too high for the dialog,
which I would then naturally like to have a vertical scrollbar. I therefore define it with the CSS style of "overflow:auto".

But what I get instead is a scrollbar over the entire dialog, while the div is contained entirely in the dialog with no scrollbar at all.

I have traced the DOM, and I believe that the source of the problem is that the lightbox div containing my dialog is also defined with "overflow:auto". Apparently this takes precedence over the inner div, so that the vertical scrollbar is put on the containing div rather than on my inner div.

I am looking for a way to move the scrollbar from the dialog to the inner div. Please remember that I cannot change the CSS to get rid of the "overflow:auto" in the lightbox div that contains my html.

I can fix the problem by setting the height of the inner div to an absolute pixel value, but as I cannot predict in advance how much screen space is allocated to the other elements of the dialog or to the dialog itself, the visual results could be rather ugly.

Any ideas ?

Below is a simplistic example of the layout of the problem :

```
<div style="overflow:auto"> <!-- lightbox div -->

<!-- start of my html -->
<div style="overflow:auto !important">
<!-- high div -->
</div>
<div>
<button></button>
<button></button>
</div>
<!-- end of my html -->

</div> <!-- end of lightbox div -->
```

I should also mention that I am using Internet Explorer 9.

Comment: You say that you can't change the CSS to get rid of the "overflow:auto" in the lightbox div.  Do you mean that you can't change the stylesheets or that you aren't able/allowed to dynamically change the CSS settings on the outer div via script?

Comment: Any piece of code or example page ? And tried !important on the overflow of the div you want to overflow?

Comment: @Ann: I cannot change the lightbox CSS, since that change would apply to all of SharePoint. No SharePoint administrator in his right mind would allow that.

Comment: @RaphaelDDL: Already tried "!important" - no difference (should have mentioned it in the post.) Added an example.

Comment: Have you tried setting a height/width on the div you have control over?  if that is smaller than the outer div it should prevent the outer div from adding the scrollbars, but you'll still get them on the inner one.

Comment: @harrymc Does the lightbox code makes its width/height proportional to the screen or the inside content? Or is fixed?

Comment: @RaphaelDDL: The dialog is called with absolute size in pixels. Apparently SharePoint calculates the size and position using some unknown algorithm (which may or may not take into account the window size and what it thinks is the size of my html).

Comment: @Treborbob: As mentioned, setting the height of my div "solves" the problem, but as the dialog size is variable the results are not optimal. For a small dialog size I would end up with TWO scrollbars for both my div and the dialog.

Comment: Maybe I should also mention that SharePoint wraps up my dialog inside an iframe, but that my javascript has full access to the page. An alternative would be to fire up javascript to delete the enclosing overflow style, but I also don't know of any event that I can use. I tried the oninit of a div, but it is never invoked.

Comment: @harrymc Since you say that SharePoint wraps your dialog inside an iframe, I infer that it's a separate document.  Could you use jQuery to attach a handler to the "ready" or "load" events of that document?

Comment: @AnnL.: Unfortunately, no. The iframe document is constructed by SharePoint. Although it includes my html, my code is not at the top document level so I cannot attach to it. I don't know of any event that a part of the document can attach to when loaded, when not at the top level.

Comment: @harrymc  How about this?  If you have an image in your inner div, it would have a jQuery "load" event.  Since images tend to lag behind the rest of the document in loading, it would *probably* not fire until after the full DOM was complete.  You could attach a handler to that. Or, if you could stand having the scrollbars on screen for a second or two, you could use a timer inside your div and fire a method to change the outer div's style after enough time has passed that everything is loaded and set up.

Comment: @AnnL.: Good thinking: I tried the onload & oninit events of an img. Unfortunately both were never invoked in either IE9 or Firefox.

Comment: @harrymc Hmm.  I wonder if there's a javascript error somewhere on your page.  That can cause javascript to stop functioning.  You've mentioned in your comments several events that you expected to fire, that didn't.  I find jQuery (if that's what you're using) very reliable as far as events firing, which makes me wonder if something is preventing your events from firing.

Comment: @AnnL.: No error, just the image was missing. Apparently img.onload only fires after a successful image load, and img.oninit doesn't work at all. I will be trying this as a solution and will report later. In the meantime feel free to post this as an answer.

Comment: @harrymc Sorry, it's wrong place to comment, but please have a look at the edit at http://superuser.com/questions/448012/can-i-set-dial-up-connections-as-metered. I don't have enough reputation there to comment directly on your reply. // Moderators: please give Harry a chance to read this comment, don't delete it instantly.

Comment: @harrymc that relates not only to Bluetooth dialup connections, but to CDMA modems, Ethernet and all connections except Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint has a funny way of calculating the height of the html I supply it for using inside the dialog. It probably calculates it while it is detached from the page, so that CSS positioning cannot work. Any attempt to use a clever CSS schema, such as [proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848904/how-to-have-scrollbars-on-an-inner-div-not-on-the-dialog/7934736#7934736) by Alexey Ivanov, therefore fails totally, with SP miscalculating the html as being extremely short. The best solution is this way butchered by SP not supplying a framework with a size for the CSS to position the elements inside.

So we are left with a javascript solution. As my html is not inserted at the topmost level of the iframe, I have no access to any body events. The only solution is then to use the onload event of an img element, as the only hookable event available, as [counseled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848904/how-to-have-scrollbars-on-an-inner-div-not-on-the-dialog/7908986#7908986) by Ann L. Unfortunately, a real image must successfully be loaded for this event to fire, so if necessary one can add a minimal 1-by-1 pixel image, which even it can be gotten out of the way with a style of "display:none".

The onload event is to contain javascript commands that will calculate the size of the dialog, subtract the total size of all elements except our maybe-too-high div, and set the height of this div to the calculated difference.

As DOM-traversal is quite broken in Internet Explorer, jQuery can be used to "fix" it by working around the bugs. If jQuery is not available, strong-arm methods can be used, such as looping on `document.getElementsByTagName('div')` to locate the divs of interest.

The SP divs that contain the supplied html can be identified by their className :

- **ms-dlgContent** : the dialog itself
- **ms-dlgFrameContainer** : the inner div that contains our html as its innerHTML and has the style of "overflow:auto" that conflicts with our own.

For the later, I have not managed to find any way of overriding its style of "overflow:auto". I finally settled for deleting its className by setting it to null. Not too big a loss, as the only style it contains is this same troublesome "overflow:auto".

All in all, quite a lot of work, both mental and programming, just because the SP programmers lacked a big enough imagination to take CSS positioning into account.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? If you have an image in your inner div, it would have a jQuery "load" event. Since images tend to lag behind the rest of the document in loading, it would *probably* not fire until after the full DOM was complete. You could attach a handler to that.

Or, if you could stand having the scrollbars on screen for a second or two, you could use a timer inside your div and fire a method to change the outer div's style after enough time has passed that everything is loaded and set up.

Comment: I have tried this solution, and although it works after a hell of a lot of fiddling and overcoming IE bugs, it is still rather fiddly and chancy, requiring quite a lot of javascript. Also, jQuery is not always available, although it could simplify the task a bit.

Comment: Ann, you get the bounty as your answer is the closest to my solution as detailed in the answer I added.

Answer (score 1):

First, I made this assumptions:

1. SharePoint lightbox do one of the following:

   - It's set width and height on itself.
   - **OR** It's positioning itself with position: absolute/relative.
   - **OR** It's loads content inside iframe.
2. Content that is not inside the inner overflow block (i. e. buttons) have fixed height.

If this assumptions are valid, then you probably can achieve described effect by position inner div div with "position: absolute", and entering left, right, top and bottom coordinates.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/GxDcW/

Comment: This is the most elegant of solutions, but unfortunately it is butchered by SharePoint. SharePoint thinks that the height of the "scroller"class is negligible, so it only allocates it a few dozens of pixels. The results is that the dialog is squeezed down vertically, and everything is just mashed-up.

Comment: Also, I don't control the CSS of the placeholder div, so cannot set it to "position: relative".

Comment: div.placeholder in my example is a part of content while .parent is a div created by sharepoint for the situation then .parent don't have "position: relative;" itself (Can be ommited if it is set), so just place it in content zone. I have some ideas how to fix code to work with SharePoint trying to shrink itself, but I need to know how this shrinking squeezing first. Can you make an example of generated lightbox html/css code and post it somewhere for me to explore?

Comment: Very hard to make an example, as the SharePoint code is quite large and complex. I also don't know how it evaluates the dialog's size. I am afraid that it needs something more substantial for the height, while your solution basically doesn't define the height at all. I am starting to suspect that the only solution would be to give the "scroller" div a fixed height of 70% of the page-height or similar.

Comment: Can you look how it collapses it then in some dom inspector? Is it using height or max-height on first scroller or one of his parents? Is it setting it dynamically, based on content and place or it hardcoded somewhere (in max-height case)? If it is max-heigh it have hardcoded fixed value, or it's value hardcoded, but set in percents, or it is fixed. but dynamically setted? Etc.

Comment: It is a fixed absolute value in pixels, apparently calculated by SharePoint when adding the iframe to the document. I have no idea how it calculates the height of my html, but whatever the algorithm, it is surely not particularly smart.

Comment: Try the following: Set div.placeholder "height: 1000px; max-height: 100%;", this way it will have height until the height is applied to it's parent, and then it is applied, it's height become 100%. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/GxDcW/2/

Comment: Does not work in my context - everything is still squashed down. SharePoint is not a very forgiving environment.

Comment: Hmm. Does your iframe content body and html tags have "height: 100%;" if not, can you set them manually? I tested it in actual iframe, not div with overflow. It worked for me: http://stackoverflow.boxofnerdythings.com/nestedoverflow/ If it's still not working, can you copy exact iframe insertion code that SharePoint generates and exact code that you place inside iframe?

Comment: Also, can you try to insert .placeholder with fixed height, but without max-heigh and say does SharePoint set iframe height correctly?

Comment: I have no control over the iframe or .placeholder. Any fixed height attribute causes SharePoint to base the dialog size on it, and it is never recalculated again - in short making a mess. I am afraid that your solution is too intelligent to make work in the context of bloody primitive SharePoint that has probably never heard of the niceties of CSS positioning.

Comment: Stop. Did you place div.placeholder content inside the content zone? Without it solution didn't work. In my example the following code must go inside the content zone: http://jsfiddle.net/GxDcW/4/ (example with comment)

Comment: Alexey, I appreciate your efforts, but I really don't have any control over the page, the iframe and placeholder div. I control only the scroller and buttons divs, and that is simply not enough. SharePoint keeps shooting down any solution based on css positioning because it probably calculates the height of my pure html without giving it a containing frame-work that is the size of the window, and without such a frame-work your beautiful css cannot work.

Comment: Sorry for my obtrusiveness. I thought that buttons also is part of inserted content, not only scroller div. Now I understand that buttons also a part of the default markup and content around them and scroller is also out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get rid of the `overflow: auto` from the lightbox div with css or HTML, but you can with javascript. You don't need jquery or Mootools, a snippet of inline javascript should be fine

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var lightbox = document.body.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
    ligthbox.style.overflow = "visible";
</script>
```

This assumes the lightbox div is the first div on your page. If it's not, you can perhaps target it with it's `id` using `getElementById` or by targeting some wrapper div first.
Any other solution with css or html would most probably involve making it (over)complicated and error prone.